# Powershell run function on leaving text form not working

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I have a script where I enter a powerbi workspace id in a GUI, after leaving this field I want it to display this workspace name in a field at the bottom of the gui, however when running the script it keeps loading indefinitely and does not display a result.

Below are the two parts of code I use

```
Function Run {
    $SaveBIID = $PowerBIID.Text
    $PowerBIN = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Id $PowerBIID.Text
    $PowerBIFound.text = $PowerBIN.Name
}

$PowerBIID.Add_Leave({
    Run
})
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing - you want to `exit` powershell immediately after updating the form?

Comment: Sorry I put the `exit` because I thought it was stuck in the function

Comment: @RobertPS as said. This is a very confusing bit of code.  The term run is terrible!!
I will give you more in a min but I am not sure you will get what you want.

Comment: Maybe this?
```Function DoStuff {
    param(
        [parameter(mandatory = $true)][PSCustomObject]$PowerBIID
    )
    #what are you doing with @$SaveBIID ?
    $SaveBIID = $PowerBIID.Text
    $PowerBIN = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Id $PowerBIID.Text
    $PowerBIFound.text = $PowerBIN.Name
    #what are you trying to get the function to do besides above ?
    Return
}

DoStuff -PowerBIID $PowerBIID```

Comment: @RobertPS also take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @dcaz I want to keep the workspace id in the variable `$SaveBIID` because I want to use it later.

The above code needs to convert the workspace id to a workspace name, so when you exit the `$PowerBIID` field it should run the function `DoStuff` and fill the field with the workspace name.

It runs fine if I do it outside the gui but as soon as I do it through the gui it hangs on running the function.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen take another peek if you get a min i am at a loss.

Comment: @RobertPS Can you add some of your gui code - I assume `$PowerBIFound` is your forms field? Can you try replacing `$PowerBIID.Text` with a static value? If it is blank for some reason, then `Get-PowerBIWorkspace` may be waiting for input on `-Id`, suppressed within the function.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I have add some GUI code to the question.
Static filling the field `$PowerBIID.Text` gives the same problem